# Storing a route in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geojson

I'm developing a backend for moblie app. Mobile apps can start/stop gps tracking, so and the end we have some kind of a Route objects. They sends their gps coordinates (lng/lat) to server every 10-30 seconds (maybe often). The question is: what is the best way to store this coordinates in mongo?

I can store them as [GeoJson LineString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#linestring) for example, but what if a route would be too long? Document max size is 16 Mb, as far as I remember. And can I update this object dynamically using some update query? I mean every time app send new point just add it to the end without taking all object from db add new point to it and saving.

Maybe it makes sense to store every point as a document?

Comment: 16Mb is quite enough, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to append to your geo coordinates i.e.

```
db.collection.update({'_id': 'foo'}, {'$push': {'geo_field.coordinates': [999,999]}})
```

As for 16 MB document size limit if you feel you can exceed it you have some other options:

- store the coordinates as [geopoint(s)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#Point) and use an other field to group your lines
- use a combination of '$each' and '$slice' to limit the array size to last n elements as the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262871/updating-array-with-push-and-slice)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [geodna](http://www.geodna.org) and maybe store the geodna of the starting coordinates and only deltas for the rest of the points in the route.